# add column to mailboxer migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, migration, message

I wanted to add two columns to the migration that makes the notifications for the mailboxer gem. When I place both in the migration that creates the notification and then run a migration it goes through. I then input them into the form and when I submit them there are no errors and the log shows that its take them. For some reason when I try to display them they don't show up, the only thing that is showing is the original things that were part of the migration which is subject and body. My question is how can I add columns to this migration?

Here is the migration with my two columns of lat and long added to the notifications section.

```
 # This migration comes from mailboxer_engine (originally 20110511145103)
 class CreateMailboxer < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def self.up    
   #Tables
     #Conversations
      create_table :conversations do |t|
        t.column :subject, :string, :default => ""
        t.column :created_at, :datetime, :null => false
        t.column :updated_at, :datetime, :null => false
     end    
      #Receipts
     create_table :receipts do |t|
       t.references :receiver, :polymorphic => true
       t.column :notification_id, :integer, :null => false
       t.column :read, :boolean, :default => false
       t.column :trashed, :boolean, :default => false
       t.column :deleted, :boolean, :default => false
       t.column :mailbox_type, :string, :limit => 25
       t.column :created_at, :datetime, :null => false
       t.column :updated_at, :datetime, :null => false
     end    
      #Notifications and Messages
     create_table :notifications do |t|
       t.column :type, :string
       t.column :body, :text
       t.column :subject, :string, :default => ""
       t.column :lat, :text
       t.column :long, :text
       t.references :sender, :polymorphic => true
       t.references :object, :polymorphic => true
       t.column :conversation_id, :integer
       t.column :draft, :boolean, :default => false
       t.column :updated_at, :datetime, :null => false
       t.column :created_at, :datetime, :null => false
     end    


   #Indexes
     #Conversations
     #Receipts
     add_index "receipts","notification_id"

     #Messages  
     add_index "notifications","conversation_id"

   #Foreign keys    
     #Conversations
     #Receipts
     add_foreign_key "receipts", "notifications", :name => "receipts_on_notification_id"
     #Messages  
     add_foreign_key "notifications", "conversations", :name =>  "notifications_on_conversation_id"
   end

   def self.down
   #Tables      
     remove_foreign_key "receipts", :name => "receipts_on_notification_id"
     remove_foreign_key "notifications", :name => "notifications_on_conversation_id"

   #Indexes
     drop_table :receipts
     drop_table :conversations
     drop_table :notifications
   end
 end
```

My show view looks like

```
 %h1= conversation.subject
 %ul
   = content_tag_for(:li, conversation.receipts_for(current_user)) do |receipt|
     - message = receipt.message
     %h3= message.subject
     %p= message.body
     %p= message.lat
     %p= message.long

 = render 'messages/form', conversation: conversation
```

This is what comes up in the console, for lat and long you see it says null

```
   Notification Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "notifications".* FROM "notifications" ORDER BY   "notifications"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 --- !ruby/object:Message
 attributes:
   id: 4
   type: Message
   body: game
   subject: wiz
   lat: !!null 
   long: !!null 
   sender_id: 1
   sender_type: User
   conversation_id: 2
   draft: false
   updated_at: 2013-03-10 04:37:54.984277000Z
   created_at: 2013-03-10 04:37:54.984277000Z
   notified_object_id: !!null 
   notified_object_type: !!null 
   notification_code: !!null 
   attachment: !!null 
  => nil
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand exactly what you are doing, but it sounds like possibly you haven't added the two new columns to attr_accessible and they aren't being saved because of that.  That's the first thing I would check (it's in the model).

Otherwise, go to the console and see if your new columns are there and see if there is data in them.  That will help you find where the problem is.

Comment: I added the columns to the attr_accessibe and that didn't do anything. When I look in the console the columns say !!null

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the columns saying that.  If you just type "Notification" in the rails console.  What do you see?  Also what do you see when you do "Notification.first".  Maybe add that to your question as an edit.

Comment: Edited my post to include the console output

Comment: You probably need to watch your logs to see what is happening.  Look at the parameters passed to the "create" action from the form and make sure those lat/long values are in there.  Then look at the SQL statement executed to create the record and see if you can see anything.  If it's not attr_accessible, then I am guessing the mailboxer gem is doing a create or save specifically with certain fields.